# How to manually trigger a dag from future in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

For example, I set the dag run every 10 days. its latest `start_time` is `2019-11-30`.
So the next `start_time` will be `2019-12-10`.

[image]

However, I want it to run in advance occasionally. As today is `2019-12-04`, How can I trigger the dag from the future?  Or is there any way to run the future dag manually?

#### what I tried

Although I click the `Trigger DAG` button, it just hang there without executing any task.

[image]

Comment: Whats your use-case? If you need to ingest "future" values using [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html) you can use `{{ next_ds }}`.

Comment: oh, I forgot to say, the trigger is temporary, just trigger once, not regularly.

Comment: @DennisLi you can edit your question if you forgot to add some info.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov yes, I already added.

Answer (score 0):

It can be triggered from the command line using the `trigger_dag` command, e.g., for the next run in your case:

```sh
airflow trigger_dag --exec_date '2019-11-30 10:00:00+00:00' my_dag
```

Comment: is it the same effect as click the Trigger DAG button? It can't execute any task yet.

Comment: @DennisLi In the command line you can specify a custom execution date as I have shown in the example. On clicking the Trigger DAG button the execution date will always be the current datetime. Regarding why the tasks are not executed, it is hard to say without the code.

Comment: it just hang there after I execute your command line. see the what I tried in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean run the scheduled `2019-12-10` to execute on today's date ? You can definitely run/trigger a dag manually but it won't act as if it was run on 2019-12-10. You can see the difference on the UI. [image]

The one without the black outline was triggered manually using the TriggerDAG button on the UI. My interval was every 10 minutes. As you can see, the manually triggered DAG is finished but it was push through by the scheduled DAG, then the `next scheduled` DAG scheduled was run after my triggered DAG.

Comment: yes, I know there is a trigger DAG button. but as the dag is from future, so even I click the trigger button, the airflow still do nothing. it can't execute the future tasks.